# Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton

Tags: matlab

Hello i'm having issues with this code line i'm a matlab newbie, i'm just trying to get all the entries of a non square matrix thanks.

```
 X=double(imread(I));
 Y=zeros(size(X,1),size(X,2));
 Ie=zeros(1,256);
 h = calchisto(I);
 [~ , b]= max(h);
 [~ , c]= max(max(X));
 [~ , d]= min(min(X));
 size(X,1)
 size(X,2)
 for i = 1 : size(X,1)
    for j = 1 : size(X,2)
        Y(i,j)=(b-1)*((X(i,j)-d)./(c-d));
        Ie(1,abs(floor(Y(i,j)+1)))=Ie(1,abs(floor(Y(i,j)+1)))+1;
    end
 end
```

Comment: ps: it says the error is from this line `Y(i,j)=(b-1)*((X(i,j)-d)./(c-d));`

Comment: What are the dimensions of `(b-1)*((X(i,j)-d)./(c-d))`?

Comment: X is a 980*767 matrix, b c and d are constants

Comment: I can't reproduce the error using those dimensions. Have you confirmed that these are the dimensions at runtime?